# Android Second activity does not load

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Sorry for my English.

I'm trying to use a second activity in Android, but it doesn't load. It's like the code jump it. Below, you can see the code. Thanks.

1- First Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     addListenerOnButton();


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btenviardados);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("helooo");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.seven.reader.activity_janela1.class);

             startActivity(intent);
            System.out.println("ebadasdadas");

        }

    });

}
```

2- Second Activity

```
public class activity_janela1 extends Activity 

{

public void OnCreate(Bundle saveInstaceState)
{
    super.onCreate(saveInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_janela1);
  }}
```

3- First layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I&apos;m screen 1 (main.xml)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btenviardados"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me to another screen" />
```

4- Second layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layoutFormulario"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Im screen 2 (main2.xml)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

5- AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.seven.reader"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.example.seven.reader.activity_janela1" >
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have created a method within your oncreate. Remove that and leave it in onCreate.

```
///public void addListenerOnButton() {



button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btenviardados);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("helooo");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.seven.reader.activity_janela1.class);

         startActivity(intent);
        System.out.println("ebadasdadas");

    }

});
```

You are misunderstanding how to use methods and scope. I recommend you do a read up on these things.

Comment: Hi, i did that. But didn't work :/. You can see the new code in the first lines of my answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your method addListenerOnButton().
You could define a method which will be executed when button is clicked via xml just add **onClick** attribute where you have defined your button.
As:-

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btenviardados"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click me to another screen"
android:onClick="click" />
```

And define click method in MainActivity.java
as:-

```
public void click(View view)
{
System.out.println("helooo");
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.seven.reader.activity_janela1.class);

 startActivity(intent);
 System.out.println("ebadasdadas");
}
```

Or you can add OnClickListener in you onCreate method of MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may help you:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 {
 Button button;
    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btenviardados);
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("helooo");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, activity_janela1.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
        System.out.println("ebadasdadas");
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: You posted an answer that was already posted by @MsYvette  . This doesn't add anything new. I DVed (BTW)